# ImportError when running a Python script from within a Shell script

Tags: python-2.7, shell, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a small shell script, which at the end invokes a small Python script. The end of shell script is as follows:

```
echo $pythonFilePath
cd $pythonFilePath

python Python-webtest.py
```

I have made the Python-webtest.py as executable. However, when the shell script is executed, I get the following error, coming from the python script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python-webtest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

The following is my python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.Firefox()
```

I have no issues when I try to run the stand alone python script and executes without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I try on my machine and it's working, the unique difference that you didn't mentioned and maybe is the reason for why it's not working for you is that I introduced selenium in the windows environment variables.

- Right click on Computer->properties (or just go to Control
  Panel\System and Security\System)
- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click on Advanced
- Click Environment Variables.
- In the section System Variables,find the PATH environment variable
  and select it.
- Click Edit.  If the PATH environment variable of selenium does not
  exist in the list,add it at the end and save.

**IMPORTANT: don't delete the existing environment variables**

Comment: Thanks @Carlo. I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and I installed selenium using `pip install selenium`.

Comment: Oh ok... yeah I use pip as well but in windows pip doesn't introduce selenium in the environment variables. In any case I would suggest to introduce the use of Ubuntu in your question or title.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. I had a python installation from anaconda and while, I had done a `pip install` it appears to have done within the anaconda installation directory. I completely removed anaconda and then did `pip install -U selenium` and ran the shell script and without any issues, the python script also did its job.